# Accessing the intrinsic type hash functions for tr1/unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I'm messing around with the `unordered_map` class template, and I'd like to write a custom hasher for my class.  The documentation for it mentions that default hashing functions are provided for the intrinsic types.  So, if you declare:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, int> foo;
```

You automatically get a hasher defined for you.

There's a good example on here on how to provide a functor if you want a custom hash function.

However, what if I have a complex class that has a `std::string` member that I would like to use as the key for insertion/deletion into the `unordered_map`?  I don't want to rewrite my own hasher. I want to leverage what was already written for the `std::string` type.

Answer (score 1):

The default hash functor is provided by `std::hash<T>` which returns `size_t`.

So you can combine the hash from several members of the class e.g. by computing `(std::hash<T>()(a) + prime * (std::hash<T>()(b) + prime * std::hash<T>()(c)))`.

Comment: Ok, so I should be able to do:

std::hash<std::string>(mystring)?

Comment: You need to instantiate the functor. `std::hash<std::string>()(mystring)` should work.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do this and I got a message that 'hash' is not a member of 'std'.  This is using g++ 4.2.1 on MacOS.  I can provide the source of the sample if you wish.

Comment: Use `std::tr1::hash` or a newer compiler, that implements C++0x in the `std` namespace.

Comment: My mistake.  I neglected to add the extra parens like you had shown above.  It's available in std::tr1::hash in gcc-4.2.1.  Thanks a lot for your help!